# Recording bar shows up in chat bar; can't remove

Tags: iphone, ios

Ever since I upgraded to 9.0, a recording bar sporadically shows up in my text input window:
[image]

It overlays on text that I try to type.

I know I'm doing it, but I don't know how I'm doing it; nor do I know how remove it.

I cannot select it, changing keyboard layout via "123" or ":)" doesn't changing anything.

The only way I know how to remove is by turning the phone off and back on.

How do I remove this bar?

Comment: I had this bug on a iOS9 beta... I didn't find how to fix it :/ You are in 9.0 or 9.0.2 ?

Comment: @MrMojoRisin 9.0.2